# change the Properties File default value to the place where my properties files existed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, internationalization

I want to change the default value of Properties File 
to the place where my properties files existed
I don't want to do that manually every time
[image]

for example I want to make the default value of Properties Files =
webapp\WEB-INF\classes\messages_ar.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Intellij are you using?

Version 13.1.3 automatically selects one of the existing property files in the project and keeps previously selected file when used multiple times.

See details for this feature on Jetbrains website http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/extracting-hard-coded-string-literals.html

You may need to mark your folder as "resources root"

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1 I will try this version :)

Comment: I still cannot change the default value !

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the default value, but when you actually perform the refactoring the last used value should stay there.

Comment: How will I do the refactoring ?

Comment: select a property you want to extract -> Refactor -> Internationalize -> fill in all fields (including property files) -> OK

Comment: I did that and it is still show me another directory \src\main\resources\props\ but I want src\main\webapp\classes

Comment: I changed my folder and market it as "resuorces root" so it works :)